# Make a observable containing a Behavioursubject flat

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I made a function to register a user in my application. For that I wrote the following code:

```
onRegister() {
    const data = {
      firstName: this.form.value.firstName,
      lastName: this.form.value.lastName,
      emailAddress: this.form.value.emailAddress
    };

    this.userService.getUserByEmail(data)
      .map(response => {
        const authData = {
          uid: response.uid,
          newUser: response.newUser
        };
        return authData;
      })
      .do(authData => this.accountService.addUsersToAccount(authData, data))
      .map(authData => {
        if (authData.newUser) {
          return this.userService.createUser(data, authData, 5);
        } else {
          return this.accountService.addAccountToUser(data, authData, 5);
        }
      })
      .subscribe((resp: Observable<User>) => {
        console.log('added user to account', resp);
      });
}
```

In my subscribe function I want to console.log the added user. At the moment resp is a observable holding a Behavioursubject with the desired value. The structure of resp is the following:

added user to account: Observable

```
- source: Observable
-- source: BehavoirSubject
--- value: Object  (<<<< this is the data I want in my console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your createUser returns an Observable of Users. You can use `flatMap()` instead of `map()` to flatten this and get the User in you `subscribe`

Comment: Hi Mark. When I change the map() function to flatMap() I get the following typescript error:

[ts] Argument of type '(authData: { uid: any; newUser: any; }) => void | Observable<User>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { uid: any; newUser: any; }, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
       Type 'void | Observable<User>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.